# How to justify that x∈B ⟺ ∀i∈I:x∈B

Tags: proof-explanation, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Why does ∀i∈I:x∈B∧x∉Ai equal to x∈B ∧ ∀i∈I:x∉Ai. how to drag the x∈B out from inside the universal quantifier. Isn't it equal to (∀i∈I:x∈B) ∧ (∀i∈I:x∉Ai) instead of x∈B ∧ ∀i∈I:x∉Ai?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your question so that we will know completely for sure what you meant and clarify what $A$ ($A_i$?) and $B$ are.

Comment: But $i$ is not present into $x∈B$ and thus $(∀i∈I:x∈B)$ is the same as $x∈B$.

Comment: @SK19: I don't there is anything unclear here -- certainly not anything that would possibly be clarified by using the prettier fonts MahJax gives you. **Learning MathJax is not as requirement for asking questions on this site**.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I added the definitions of $A$ and $B$ to my comment. No, not a requirement, but if OP can't at least write A_i I think having a look at MJ could make things easier for both parties.

Comment: Thank you but I'm still confused, if I let i be arbitrary and  treat i ∈ I as P and x ∈ B as Q, is it justified to conclude Q only from knowing P->Q. @MauroALLEGRANZA . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long comment*

$∀i∈I:x∈B ∧ x∉A_i$ is equivalent to : $∀i (i∈I \to (x∈B ∧ x∉A_i))$ that in turn is equivalent to : $∀i (i∈I \to x∈B) ∧ ∀i (i∈I \to x∉A_i)$.

Thus, the issue is to show that :

> $∀i (i∈I \to x∈B) \equiv x∈B$.

Two cases :

*(i)* $x \in B$ is TRUE. Thus, by truth-table for conditional (i.e. $\to$) $(i∈I \to x∈B)$ holds, for $i$ whatever.

*(ii)* $x \in B$ is FALSE.

We assume that $I$ is not empty: in this case, $j \in I$, for some $j$.

Thus $(j∈I \to x∈B)$ is FALSE and thus $∀i(i∈I \to x∈B)$ is FALSE.

*The only issue is when* $I = \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh yes, what if the statement is vacuously true, than it is possible for x∈B to be false but the conditional true. and another thing, what if j is not an element of I? This will cause for x∈B to be possibly false or true while the conditional till holds.

Comment: I've tried to see whether x∈ ⋂i∈I(B∖Ai) is true or false, and found out that it is a vacuously true statement, therefore the statement is true for any x, then B = U where U is the universe of discourse, this is false unless we let B=U thus the equality doesn't hold. And therefore I think it is same to assume I is never an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of distributive property of intersection of $B$ with the complement of $A_i$

$$B\cap \left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\big(\overline{A_i}\big)\right) = \bigcap_{i\in I}\left(B\cap \overline{A_i}\right)$$

Comment: @SK19 Thanks for edit.

Comment: When I try to prove this property, I encounter the same problem as the question, as I want to prove (<--) How can I justify that from knowing, (∀i∈I:x∈B)  I can conclude x∈B?? Thanks